# lit-element passing data from one component to another

Tags: polymer-3.x, lit-element, lit-html

I am currently learning how to user lit-element v2.0.0-rc.2 I have two components app.js and list-items.js. In app.js I am collecting data from local storage and storing it in this.todoList, Im then calling this.todoList in my list-items.js but the problem I am running into is that it is not passing the data as an array but as an object, I am trying to output that data in list-items all Im getting when I do a console.log of this.todoList is [object] in my

tags it is rendering out with dots for the tag but no data. I was wondering If i could get some help in understanding why this is happening . here is my code 
    app.js
    '''
    import {LitElement, html} from 'lit-element';
    import './add-item';
    import './list-items';

```
class TodoApp extends LitElement{

static get properties(){
    return{
        todoList: Array
    }
}

constructor(){
    super();
    let list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo-list'));
    this.todoList = list === null ? [] : list;

}

render(){
    return html `
    <h1>Hello todo App</h1> 
    <add-item></add-item>  
    <list-items todoList=${this.todoList}></list-items>     
    `;
    }
}

customElements.define('todo-app', TodoApp)

list-items.js
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';
import {repeat} from 'lit-html/directives/repeat.js';
import './todo-item';

class ListItems extends LitElement {
static get properties(){
    return{
        todoList: Array
    }
}

constructor(){
    super();
    this.todoList = [];

}

render(){
    console.log(this.todoList)
    return html `
        <ul>${repeat(this.todoList, (todo) => html`<todo-item 
todoItem=${todo.item}></todo-item`)}</ul>
    `;
    }
}

customElements.define('list-items', ListItems);
'''
```

the result I am looking for is the for the data stored in local storage to be listed on my rendered page.

Comment: seems like you did the same tutorial I'm doing. Did you ever finish the code?

Comment: Yes I did , I followed the answer given by Thad .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Attributes are always text. Because `todoList` an array, it's a property, not attribute. Try binding as a property: `.todoList="${this.todoList}"`. See https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/templates#bind-properties-to-child-elements  (Updated link for Lit, https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#property-expressions)

Comment: Thad thank you for the help this answered my question and I learned more in the process always good when that happens. Thanks again